# MongoDB and express call not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I've tried multiple things and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am new to backend services and am not sure where to start looking for the issue.

app.js

```
 // SERVER SETUP

    var express = require ('express');
    var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
    var app = express();
    var router = express.Router();
    var routes = require('./routes');
    var transactions = require('./routes/routes');

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

//API ROUTES

    router.use(function (req, res, next){
        console.log('Something is happening. . .');
        next();
      });

// REGISTER ROUTES
     app.use('/', router);

     app.get('/transactions', transactions.getRecords);

// START THE SERVER
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('Server is running on port ' + port);
```

model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function (callback){
    console.log('Mongo Connected');
  });

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var BankSchema = new Schema({
     _id: String,
    date: Date,
    account: String,
    location: String,
    amount: Number,
    type: String,
    reason: {
        type: String,
        explanation: String
     }
  });

 exports.transactions = mongoose.model('BudgetApp', BankSchema, 'transactions');
```

routes.js

```
var useModel = require('./model');

var bankData = useModel.transactions;

var transactions = function (callback){
    var records = []

    bankData.aggregate([

            {$match: {type:"debit"} },

            {$group:{
                _id:{
                    month: {$month: "$date"}, 
                    year:{$year: "$date"}
                },
            expense: {
                $sum:"$amount"
                }
            }
        },
        {$project: {
            date: "$_id",
            spent: "$expense"
        }}
    ], function (err, data){
        if (err){ console.log(err);}
            console.log(data);
            records.push(data);
        });

    callback(records);
 };//transactions

exports.getRecords = function (req, res){
    transactions(function (err, transaction){
        if (err){console.log(err);}
        res.json(transaction);
    });
};
```

When I run the node server, the console log only returns and empty array, with no errors. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You have mentioned the localhost. But did you configure the port with localhost url? If not then try putting your port number on which your mongo server is running. Please let me know whether it helped or not. :)

Comment: I'm not even sure if I have the url correct or how to set up the url for mongodb

Comment: If you have just installed Mongo db following their tutorial, then just replace "mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test')" with "mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')". Just give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The callback in your transactions function needs to be executed within the callback of the aggregate query. Since the query is asynchronous, `callback(records)` will execute before the query is completed, passing an empty array to the callback. In addition, the callback is looking for two parameters: an Error and an Array. If you don't have an error, you want to do `callback(null, records)`. In your current code, you're passing the records to the error argument which will just be consoled logged (which is why you see an empty array).

Beyond that, your `records` variable is redundant. The data you receive from aggregate is the only data you'll have. The transaction function could be simplified to:

```
var transactions = function (callback){

    bankData.aggregate([
        {$match: ... },
        {$group: ... },
        {$project: ... }
    ], callback);
 };
```

As an aside for code quality, this line is painful to read:

`exports.transactions = mongoose.model('BudgetApp', BankSchema, 'transactions');`

In two files, you've referred to the same data as *BudgetApp*, *BankSchema*, *Transactions*, and *BankData*.
Be consistent. Right now, it's being saved under the mongo collection *transactions*, so name it that:

```
// model.js (you could even name it transaction.js)
module.exports = mongoose.model("Transaction", TransactionSchema)
// routes.js
var Transaction = require("./model")
```

Give it one name, and refer to it as that everywhere you use it, or someone reading your code will have no idea what any variable represents.

Comment: I made the suggested changes but am now getting 
"Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators".

Comment: That sounds like a syntax error of missing closing/opening `{}`. It means that you're using a wrong $operator for one of the match/group/project